# Pandas - Changing header in a Dataframe using data in another Dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I am trying to rename columns of my Dataframe using data available in another Dataframe. Given below are the dataframes I currently have:

Dataframe 1:

```
emp_id, Week 41, Week 40, Week 39, Week 38
101, 3, 5, 5, 7 
102, 2, 6, 4, 3
103, 7, 5, 3, 6
```

Dataframe 2:

```
week, date
Week 35, Aug-29 - Sep-03
Week 36, Sep-05 - Sep-10
Week 37, Sep-12 - Sep-17
Week 38, Sep-19 - Sep-24
Week 39, Sep-26 - Oct-01
Week 40, Oct-03 - Oct-08
Week 41, Oct-10 - Oct-15
```

Mapping of these Dataframe is using the Week number to date and use that in the main Dataframe

I would like to get the below as the final output:

```
emp_id, Oct-10 - Oct-15, Oct-03 - Oct-08, Sep-26 - Oct-01, Sep-19 - Sep-24
101, 3, 5, 5, 7 
102, 2, 6, 4, 3
103, 7, 5, 3, 6
```

Comment: Assuming that the dataframes are `df1` and `df2` respectively, do you sharing the output of `print(df1.dtypes)` and
`print(df2.dtypes)`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.rename`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html) by dictionary from `df2`:

```
df1 = df1.rename(columns=df2.set_index('week')['date'].to_dict())
```

Answer (score 1):

We can do that by using `map` like so :

```py
df1.columns = df1.columns.map(df2.set_index('week')['date'].get)
```

Or also by using the [`rename`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html) method :

```py
d = dict(zip(df2['week'], df2['date']))
df1 = df1.rename(columns=d)
```

Output :

```
    emp_id  Oct-10 - Oct-15 Oct-03 - Oct-08 Sep-26 - Oct-01 Sep-19 - Sep-24
0   101     3               5               5               7
1   102     2               6               4               3
2   103     7               5               3               6
```

Answer (score 1):

Another possible solution:

```
(df1.melt(id_vars='emp_id', var_name='week')
 .merge(df2).pivot(index='emp_id', columns='date', values='value'))
```

Output:

```
date     Oct-03 - Oct-08   Oct-10 - Oct-15   Sep-19 - Sep-24   Sep-26 - Oct-01
emp_id                                                                        
101                    5                 3                 7                 5
102                    6                 2                 3                 4
103                    5                 7                 6                 3
```